# unable to read google converted value in cakephp text box

Tags: cakephp

Hello I wrote following code to access google converted text in textbox. But that converted text is not working in textbox but same converted text working as a label.

```
$agetSingleuser='&#2350;&#2361;&#2375;&#2358;';
<?php echo $this->Form->create('user',array('class'=>'forms'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('hindi', array('type' => 'text','id'=>'userhindi','value'=>$agetSingleuser, 'label' => '&#2350;&#2361;&#2375;&#2358;','class'=>'form-control', 'div' => 'col-lg-4 col-xs-12'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save',array( 'div' => false,'class'=>'btn','name' => 'submit'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the raw decoded string as the value for the input.

```
$agetSingleuser = html_entity_decode('&#2350;&#2361;&#2375;&#2358;');
```